# Policies on answers porting code

Tags: discussion, on-topic, off-topic

In questions such as [this](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/682/how-to-prove-gauss-summation-of-integers-with-proof-assistants-using-forward-rea), the OP asks for proofs, definitions, methodology etc. on a specific topic, but does not require a specific proof assistant*. There will imaginably be answers that are purely a *porting* of other answers, which I define to be an answer where no additional information (including proof-assistant-specific tricks or pitfalls) is given apart from translating the code to another proof assistant. For concreteness here's an example:

```
-- Agda
example : (n : Nat) -> 0 + n ≡ n
example n = refl
```

```
-- Idris, adapted from https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/theorems.html
example : (n:Nat) -> plus Z n = n
example n = Refl
```

This would count as porting, *unless* the emphasis is on, for example, how Idris has upper-case requirements on constructors, or how Agda needs spaces around the colon, etc.

There are several options that I can think of:

- Allow this as long as the original answer is credited (according to the license of SE answers).
- Allow this, but require it to be posted as community wiki.
- Disallow this unless the port requires some degree of effort, or highlights language-specific aspects.

* The linked question is special because it is **biased** towards Isabelle. But there are questions like [this](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/602/how-to-represent-mathematical-partial-functions-in-a-type-theory-based-proof-ass) or [this](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/650/have-the-common-algorithms-in-existing-computer-assisted-proofs-been-transitione).

Comment: @taylor.2317 The last thing isn't meant to be an option, so it's weird to format it like that. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Oh I see, you used `*`, but it is accidentally a valid Markdown bullet. Fixed.

Comment: yes, thanks. I didn't realise it would format like this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a piece of concrete code makes a good answer, and the question is fully proof-assistant-agnostic, then porting such a piece of code to other proof assistants makes sense (it adds value for future readers who are interested in the question and know a specific proof assistant but not others).

I don't think such ports should be *always* posted as CW, since being able to port some code in one PA into another is no easy feat in general IMO. For trivial cases like the Agda-Idris example in the question, it makes sense to create a CW answer collecting multiple ports of the given code.